# finding max of quartic function $y=ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+e$ when x is in range [0.0, 1.0]

Tags: calculus

How do I find the maximum value of a quartic function when x is in range between 0 and 1?
Solving $0=4ax^3+3bx^2+2cx+d$ to get possible candidate for x that gives maximum value is not elegant and messy, as that means I have to solve cubic equation which I want to avoid.
I want to know if there are better ways to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking the derivative and then applying the cubic formula is the obvious route, though I agree that the cubic formula is rather gross in practice; to my knowledge, there aren't any particularly easy ways to find zeroes to a cubic function. The other obvious routes include approximating it graphically, etc. I'm assuming that won't suffice either.

However, look into the [AM-GM inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means). I wasn't able to find it for some reason, but I do know that there's a PDF floating around out there from UGA on how to use it in such a context. There's also [Find maximum value by using AM-GM inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3127089/find-maximum-value-by-using-am-gm-inequality), which may be of some assistance. Most of the techniques you might want to use are going to come from the field of optimization.

Edit:

[Here](http://jwilson.coe.uga.edu/EMT725/AMGM/SSMA.Bnghm.html) is the UGA article I mentioned.

I'm not sure where you are in your education, but get used to a lot of manipulation and "things coming from nowhere." It is what it is, but the creativity and ingenuity that requires is half of what makes math such a beautiful subject. At any rate, I was able to find this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qS-EqGgdNo8) which is a roughly similar problem to what you might need to do.

Comment: @nena I agree with the answer of mmmeeeker and would add that it may be helpful to also consider $y''$, which is a quadratic, and therefore has an easily dissected behavior.  Examining $y''$ should *at least help* decide whether the maximum $y$ is at one of the endpoints or whether the maximum $y$ corresponds to one of the roots of $y' = 0.$  If the latter, then I see no alternative to attacking the cubic.